# How can I access a checked Radio Button in a data bound ItemsControl?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have a ItemsControl bound to a string list.

Code:-

```
List<string> possibleAnswers;
possibleAnswers = GetPossibleAnswers(currentQuestion);
AnswerIC.Items.Clear();
AnswerIC.ItemsSource = possibleAnswers;
```

Xaml:-

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="AnswerIC" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,10">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel x:Name="AnswerSP" Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <RadioButton GroupName="AnswerRBG" Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In a button click event, I am trying to find the content of the checked radio button and am unable to. Anyone with suggestions? And I should probably add I am a complete amateur with Silverlight.

Comment: Please show the code that shows you situation and what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry bout that, the code was stripped out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do that like following

1) Register radio button Click event

> Click="RadioButton_Click"

2) Do `Tag="{Binding}"`

3)

```
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
     var contant= rb .tag;
 }
```

Comment: Don't think this will work - or if it will, I am not following. I have one submit button and on the click event of that button I am trying to find the radio button that is checked.

Comment: then you can save this result in global variable hare and pull that on Submit button click too

Comment: If you use this technique I'd recommend handling the `Checked` event, rather than `Clicked`. This will allow you to avoid unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add a click event handler to each RadioButton, you can do this by enumerating the `Items`

```
string answer = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in AnswerIC.Items)
{
    var rb = AnswerIC.ItemContainerGenerator
                     .ContainerFromItem(item).FindVisualChild<RadioButton>();

    if (rb.IsChecked ?? false)
    {
        answer = item.ToString();
        break;
    }
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select an answer");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You chose: {0}", answer));
}
```

using the following extension method (see also http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx)

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject instance) where T : DependencyObject
{
    T control = default(T);

    if (instance != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(instance); i++)
        {
            if ((control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i) as T) != null)
            {
                break;
            }

            control = FindVisualChild<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i));
        }
    }

    return control;
}
```